# Retrieve tag names from XML matching the keyword

Tags: sql-server

Please check below example

Example 1 :
**Input**

```
<report>
   <reporting_person>  
    <phones>
      <phone>        
        <tph_number>9078</tph_number>
        <tph_extension>99999</tph_extension>
        <comments>No comments</comments>
      </phone>
    </phones>
   </reporting_person>  
</report>
```

**Search String**  : 99999

**Output** : tph_extension

Example 2 :

**Input**

```
<report>
   <reporting_person>  
     <addresses>
      <address>
        <SequenceNumber>0</SequenceNumber>
        <address_type>BU</address_type>
        <town>Seiraa</town>
        <city>olympia</city>
        <zip>674537</zip>
        <country_code>SA</country_code>
        <state>Bahrain</state>
        <comments>No comments</comments>
      </address>
    </addresses>
   </reporting_person>  
</report>
```

**Search String**  : olympia

**Output** : city

Example 3 :

**Input**

```
<report>
   <reporting_person>  
     <name>Alex</name>
   </reporting_person>  
</report>
```

**Search String**  : Alex

**Output** : name

Kindly note there are no unique pattern to the XML.

Since i had to give the path (' / * / * ') to obtain the results, this was not efficient, because the keyword could be anywhere in the xml.

```
SELECT  t.c.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(max)') AS ParentNodeName,
    t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeName,
    t.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeText
FROM    @xmldataStr.nodes('/*/*') AS t(c)
where t.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '%str%'
```

Comment: @DaleK : Kindly check my code now. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
declare @xmldataStr xml = N'<report>
 <reporting_person>  
 <addresses>
  <address>
    <SequenceNumber>0</SequenceNumber>
    <address_type>BU</address_type>
    <town>Seiraa</town>
    <city>olympia</city>
    <zip>674537</zip>
    <country_code>SA</country_code>
    <state>Bahrain</state>
    <comments>No comments</comments>
  </address>
</addresses>
<test>
 <a><b>parameter x</b></a>
</test>
transaction
</reporting_person>  
</report>';

declare @str varchar(20) = 'ra';

SELECT  
   t.c.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(max)') AS ParentNodeName,
   t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeName,
   t.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeText
FROM    @xmldataStr.nodes('//*') AS t(c) -- //==anywhere in the structure, *== any element
where t.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') like concat('%', @str, '%');

SELECT 
   t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeName,
   t.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeText
--xpath filter
FROM    @xmldataStr.nodes('//*[contains(lower-case(text()[1]), lower-case(sql:variable("@str")))]') AS t(c);
```

Comment: This worked.!! The second query is sufficient for the purpose.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!